# Which sets are these parts from? White and brown cycles with no wheel?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Any ideas about these half assembled pieces that were given to me in a big star wars LEGO box?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are from a number of different Star Wars Battle Packs:

[Clone Troop Battle Pack (7913)](https://brickset.com/sets/7913-1/):

[image: 7913]

[Endor Rebel Trooper and Imperial Trooper Battle Pack (9489)](https://brickset.com/sets/9489-1/):

[image: 9489]

[Snow Trooper Battle Pack (8084)](https://brickset.com/sets/8084-1/):

[image: 8084]